# Make a phone call without clicking phone call button in android

Tags: android, telephony

I want to creat an Android app that can get phone number from a text file then make a phone call immediatelly without clicking any extra button. But, i find no way to do that. All samples on internet use the default call button to make a phone.

here is the code i used

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
      performDial();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
public void performDial(){
    if(edittext.getText()!=null){
      try { 
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + edittext.getText())));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }//if
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, I do not know if you can get the `KEYCODE_CALL` event or not in `onKeyDown()`.

Second, use `ACTION_CALL` instead of `ACTION_DIAL`. You will need to hold the `CALL_PHONE` permission for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is very Simple. Do it like this ---->

1. Fire an intent ---->
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("Tel:(+12)123456789"));
     startActivity(intent);
2. Add this permission to your manifest file ----->

And your ready to go....